# Prove $(a^3+b^3+c^3)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge(a+b+c)(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)$

Tags: cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Prove that $(a^3+b^3+c^3)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge(a+b+c)(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)$, where a, b, c > 0.

I did LHS-RHS, broke parentheses and cancelled terms.

I think I might use $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$. Then I only need to prove:

$a^5+b^5+c^5\gt abc(a^2+b^2+c^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:For your last inequality

Apply AM-GM like this $$3a^5+b^5+c^5\ge 5a^3bc$$

Comment: Cool. I just need to do the same for b and c, then added them all up to obtain the last inequality. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the last inequality is $a^5+b^5+c^5\geq abc(a^2+b^2+c^2)=a^3bc+ab^3c+abc^3$. One way to do it would be to quote Muirhead's Inequality directly, since $(5,0,0)\succ(3,1,1)$. Alternatively, using AM-GM, you obtain:

$$a^5+a^5+a^5+b^5+c^5\geq 5a^3bc$$
$$b^5+b^5+b^5+c^5+a^5\geq 5ab^3c$$
$$c^5+c^5+c^5+a^5+b^5\geq 5abc^3$$

I leave you to finish the proof using the above 3 inequalities if you do not want to use Muirhead's.

Comment: Thank you. Understand, when adding them up, it's exactly what I needed. I'll learn about Muirhead's - great to know.

Answer (score 1):

As the inequality is homogeneous, assume: $a+b+c = 3$.
We know
$$
(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^2 \geqslant 3(a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2) = (a+b+c)(a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2)
$$
We need to prove now:
$$
a^3 + b^3 + c^3\geqslant a^2 + b^2 + c^2\quad \textrm{with}\quad a+b+c=3
$$
Which is
$$
3(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) \geqslant (a+b+c) (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)
$$Obviously true.
For proof, after expansion, you can add
$$
a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \geqslant a^2b + b^2c + c^2a\ \textrm{and}\ a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \geqslant ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2
$$Proof of these are only by AM-GM.

Comment: Very glad to learn how to use the assumption $a+b+c=3$ in homogeneous inequality. Thanks for the clean writing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, C-S helps here:
$$\sum_{cyc}a^3\sum_{cyc}a^2=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}a^3\sum\limits_{cyc}a\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}a}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2\right)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}a}=$$
$$=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2\right)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}1\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}a}\geq\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2b^2\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}a\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}a}=\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2b^2\sum\limits_{cyc}a.$$

Comment: Thanks again, Michael. I tried to understand why you thought about adding $(a+b+c)$ in the first step. Is it to neutralize the power 3 down to power 2? Then from there, you split the 3 $a^2+b^2+c^2$ terms into 2+1, to match up the RHS. Magic.

Comment: @lilige   Because I want to use C-S. I want to get $(a^3+b^3+c^3)(a+b+c)$

Comment: Got it! Good trick for me to keep in mind. Cool.